# Is there a universal way of knowing if the user is holding CTRL key or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

Is there a way in JQuery or Javascript to know whether or not the user is holding the CTRL key at any point outside of events such as keyPress, keyUp and etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to achieve that.

A good solution is to save the state in a global 
variable, switched by the events you mentioned, and check that when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

No, I am afraid that there isn't.